# Why is my C# Inheritance not working with the Generic Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern

I have defined a base repository as follows:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;
    protected readonly DbContext dbContext;

    public BaseRepository()
    {
        this.dbContext = new SchoolDemoEntities();
        dbSet = dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public BaseRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
        dbSet = dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

The above is my base class for all other repository classes. One of which is Read...

```
public class ReadRepository<TEntity>
: BaseRepository<TEntity>
, IReadRepository<TEntity>
  where TEntity : class
{
    #region Constructors

    public ReadRepository() : base() { }

    public ReadRepository(DbContext dbContext)
        : base(dbContext) { }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Maps to read functionality in the database. Reads a single record.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">an integer identifier which maps to the primary key</param>
    /// <returns>TEntity -> a single instance of the class</returns>
    public TEntity Read(int id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }
}
```

The above is only part of the class, there are other read methods. Also there is one more class (delete) which inherits this read class...

```
public class DeleteRepository<TEntity>
: ReadRepository<TEntity>
, IDeleteRepository<TEntity>
  where TEntity : class
{
    #region Constructors

    public DeleteRepository() : base() { }

    public DeleteRepository(DbContext dbContext)
        : base(dbContext) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Maps to delete functionality in the database. Deletes the given record.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">A class containing the information to delete.</param>
    /// <returns>int: The number of records affected.</returns>

    #endregion


    public int Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Remove(entity);
        return dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

My problem is, as I understand inheritance, I should have access to the read method when I declare and instance of the delete class in my controller as follows:

```
public class CourseController : Controller
{
    IDeleteRepository<Course> deleteRepository = new DeleteRepository<Course>(new DbContext("SchoolDemoEntities"));

    // POST: Course/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        //*** The line directly below doesn't work ***
        Course course = deleteRepository.Read(id);


        deleteRepository.Delete(course);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

The line highlighted doesn't work. I cant see what is wrong. C# just underlines the read method saying:

> IDeleteRepository does not contain a definition for 'Read' and
>   no extension method 'Read' accepting a first argument of type
>   'IDeleteRepository' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

I do have interfaces defined, and the message is correct, it doesn't have a read. But I don't see why I need one, as the Read repo implements its own read method and this concrete implementation is inherited by delete. Why should I need to define a read method which is already defined in my read interface and class and inherited.

What lead me to this error was an issue I was trying to resolve with multiple connections to the same entity.

If I define the read class explicitly in my controller as follows:

```
    IReadRepository<Course> readRepository = new ReadRepository<Course>(new DbContext("SchoolDemoEntities"));
```

and then alter the highlighted line to read...

```
        Course course = readRepository.Read(id);
```

Then I get the error...

> The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the
>   ObjectStateManager.

Which does make sense, hence the reason for the inheritance. I need to read in the same connection as I delete. Doing it using the above method closes the connection from the read and reopens it for delete. Inheritance should resolve this I think? But when I inherit, I cannot access the read method and fail to understand why.

Comment: Are you using separate repositories for the Read and Delete actions? You should have a repository per entity that can Read and Delete. Or have I misunderstood the business case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DeleteRepository` contains the `Read` method, as it inherits from `ReadRepository`.

The issue is you're local variable is of type `IDeleteRepository<Course>` - this is no `Read` method on `IDeleteRepository<Course>`.

If you changed your declaration to the correct type, you would have access to both methods:

```
DeleteRepository<Course> deleteRepository = new DeleteRepository<Course>(new DbContext("SchoolDemoEntities"));
```

Comment: Ok...so because I am using the interface instead of the concrete implementation this is why I am having the problem...I taught I should use abstractions in, and concretes out. but thanks for your answer.

Comment: That's generally good advice.  In this case, I would expect a single `IRepository` interface with `Read` and `Delete` rather than two separate interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for your help...funny enough...it works and makes sense now! :) I have to wait 4 mins to accept the answer.

Comment: If you want `IDeleteRepsoitory` to also have `Read` then make the interface derive from `IReadRepository`.

Comment: The problem with this is then I have to implement read functionality whenever I implement the delete interface. I might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If `Read()` is on `IReadRepository`, have `IDeleteRepository` inherit from `IReadRepository` to have your interface hierarchy matching your implementation hierarchy, then the methods will be visible at the level you expect.

Although, as @Charles Mager says in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29844656/117507) `Read()` and `Delete()` should be on the base repository, since the Repository pattern should have a repository for each business object, rather than Repository action.

Comment: My only issues with having all the CRUD actions on the same interface is that I have to implement functionality in the relevant class even if its not needed. For example, if all I want it read, or bulkread, I have to implement all the functionality for the other operations and bulk operations. But this is just my limited knowledge. I may be wrong.

Comment: If it's all generic, you can implement it on the base implementation and get it for free on all the derived classes. You can override it if it's unique or shouldn't be there on derived classes.

Comment: Thanks...that's something I'll explore...I did as you suggested, cleaned up the code a lot. cheers. +1